# What's the best way to run .net framework apps on linux with docker

Tags: c#, .net, linux, docker

I need to develop and run a .NET Framework 4.6.2 application on Linux, on this case, .net core is not a possible solution, since it's a quite old and big application.

So, is it possible to develop the application on linux and run it with docker?
I would also need to run SqlServer express on the machine.

I know I could run a VM on my computer, but I wanted, if possible, in this case, not use a virtual machine

Comment: What about Mono?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your options are:

1. Run in a Linux container using Mono
2. Migrate to .NET Core/Standard (I know you said you didn't want to do this, but it might be worth investigating; if it's not an ASP. NET web app, the effort is likely pretty low as .NET Framework 4.6.2 is compatible with .NET Standard 2.0)
3. Run as-is in a Windows container

So realistically if you need to run it in a Linux container, you need to use Mono as your runtime.

Regarding SQL Express, SQL Server does now exist for Linux, with images available at Microsoft's container registry (also linked to from Docker Hub/Store)

Comment: This solution worked, Using mono to develop and deploying it into a windows docker image to run.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [Mono](https://www.mono-project.com) if you absolutely cannot port to .NET Core. That said, are you sure it's "quite old"? .NET Framework 4.6.2 is not THAT old (released just under 3 years ago), unless of course it's been ported from an older version of the .NET Framework.

Then there's [WINE](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=2586), but I would leave this as a last resort.

As for SQL Server, you can [natively install this on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup?view=sql-server-2017), or in [Docker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-docker?view=sql-server-2017&pivots=cs1-bash).

Comment: The application is more than 10 years old, but it's still being developed, so the team kept updating the .net framework version, but since i'm just a freelance to this project, I cant port it to .net core. About mono, I never tried it, does it support all the features of the .net framework?